# Input array to database

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel

Im confused to this. I try to input the array with different keys and values based on my input type, and store it to one column of my db table.

This is my input type.
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Gon.png)

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                           <div class="input-group control-group" >
                             <input type="text" name="kel_sekolah[]" class="form-control n1" placeholder="Kelurahan...">
                             <div class="input-group-btn"> 
                               <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm z2" type="button" style="padding:10px;"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add</button>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <div class="input-group control-group" >
                             <input type="text" name="rt_sekolah[]" class="form-control n1" placeholder="Rt...">
                             <div class="input-group-btn"> 
                               <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm z1" type="button" style="padding:10px;"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add</button>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>

<script>
 $(document).on('click','.z1', function(){
                          z1();
                        });
                        function z1(){
                          var kel_sekolah = '<div class="form-group p-3"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"></div><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="input-group control-group" ><input type="text" id="kel_sekolah[]" name="rt_sekolah[]" class="form-control n1" placeholder="Rt..."><span id="kel_sekolahError" class="alert-message"></span><div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove1" type="button" style="padding:10px;"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove</button></div></div></div></div>';
                          $('.myform1').append(kel_sekolah);
                        };
                        
                        $(document).on('click','.z2', function(){
                          z2();
                        });
                        function z2(){
                          var kel_sekolah = '<div class="form-group p-3"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="input-group control-group" ><input type="text" id="kel_sekolah" name="kel_sekolah[]" class="form-control n1" placeholder="Kelurahan..."><span id="kel_sekolahError" class="alert-message"></span><div class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success z2" type="button" style="padding:10px;"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add</button></div></div></div><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="input-group control-group" ><input type="text" id="kel_sekolah" name="rt[]" class="form-control n1" placeholder="Rt..."><span id="kel_sekolahError" class="alert-message"></span><div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success z1" type="button" style="padding:10px;"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add</button></div></div><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove3" type="button" style="padding:10px;"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove</button></div></div></div>';
                          $('.myform1').append(kel_sekolah);
                        };

                        $(document).on('click','.remove2', function(){
                          $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
                        });

                        $(document).on('click','.remove3', function(){
                          $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
                        });
</script>
```

This is my controller

```
  public function daftarsds(Request $request)
    {  
        $array = [];
        foreach ($request->kel_sekolah as $key) {
            foreach ($request->rt_sekolah as $value) {
            $array[] = [$key => $value];
            }
        }
        
        
        ListSekolahSd::Create([
            'nama_sekolah' => $request->nama_sekolah,
            'kuota_sekolah' => $request->kuota_sekolah,
            'kel_sekolah' => $array,
          ]);
            
    
        return redirect()->route('/admin/sd');
    }
```

This is my model

```
class ListSekolahSd extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $table = 'list_sekolah_sds';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nama_sekolah', 
        'kuota_sekolah',
        'rt_sekolah',
        'kel_sekolah',
    ];
    // protected $casts = [
    //     'kel_sekolah' => 'array',
    // ];

}
```

how can i add those 2 input to my column?
i want the column value would be like this : {"key1":["value1","value2"],"key2":["value1","value2"]}

but what i get is this : [{"key1":"value1"},{"key1":"value2"},{"key2":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}]

is there anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you need to uncomment `protected $casts`  that array cast

Comment: @KamleshPaul i already did. but it returns null array in db..

Comment: is kel_sekolah is a json field in your DB ? 
if not, then covert kel_sekolah into json fied in your DATABASE and then serialize your array and save it .

Comment: you used an empty array variable `$array` for `foreach` inside `daftarsds()`

Comment: @AlzafanChristian i update my code, can u check it? wether its correct or not?

Comment: @MasadAshraf yes it is, its a json field. what do you mean serialize it? im sorry im new in laravel

Comment: i think you just need 1 loop `foreach ($request->kel_sekolah as $key => $value)` put in on `$array` with the keys and fill it with `$request->rt_sekolah` as array
the old code works i guess, just need to change `foreach($array...` to `foreach($request->kel_sekolah...`

Comment: then just use this 
`ListSekolahSd::Create([
            'nama_sekolah' => $request->nama_sekolah,
            'kuota_sekolah' => $request->kuota_sekolah,
            'kel_sekolah' => json_encode($array),
          ]);`
in your controller .

and uncomment your cast code in your model

Comment: @AlzafanChristian yes it work, but the value is like this {"GUMALA":[["1","2","3","4","5","6"]],"GANTING":[["1","2","3","4","5","6"]]} , whenever i put the different values for different keys, the values were combined, not seperated. i edited my question. i upload the image of my input. can u check it?

Comment: then you need to add unique identifier each you add element, so you can separate the values, your current HTML have only 2 fields

Comment: @AlzafanChristian can you show me the code please?